# prestashop custom module hook with id_product

Tags: hook, prestashop

I'm developing a custom module for add a button "notify me" when product is out of stock.
this button should simply call an action and write in a custom table (created by this module)

my problem is pass the id_product to the hook

```
public function install() {

    $sql= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"._DB_PREFIX_."fasys_notify`(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL )";


    if (parent::install() == false ||  
            !$this->registerHook('notify') ||
            !$this->registerHook('displayHeader') ||
            !Db::getInstance()->Execute($sql)
        )
        return false;
        return true;
}



public function hookFasysNotify($params) {

    //NEED ID_PRODUCT HERE

    //var_dump(Tools::getValue('id_product')); //doesen't works

    $html ='<button type="button" class="notifyme_btn btn btn-info btn-default">Notify Me</button>';

    return $html ;  

}
```

in my .tpl file i have added this:

```
{hook h='fasysNotify' product=$product}
```

how can I retrieve the product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.tpl

```
{hook h='fasysNotify' product=$product}
```

module:

```
public function hookNotify($params) {

    var_dump( $params['product']  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in tpl :

```
{hook h='fasysNotify' product=$product}
```

or

```
{hook h='fasysNotify' product=$id_product}
```

in module :

```
$id_product = $param['id_product'];
```

or

```
$id_product = $param;
```